# Set value for command class object in jsp using jstl or scriptlet

Tags: spring, jsp

I have a command class in JSP and using  spring form tags. I want to set value for form : input tag in jsp itself.

How can I set it ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Then add the following in your input tag

```
<form:input type="text" path="member_variable_name"/>
```

Hope this answers your query..
See [this](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-form-tags-1.html)

Comment: dude I am using a form : input tag of spring. Not the normal input tag.Value is not a valid attribute for form : input tag.

Comment: You got it now.  But I want to set the path value in JSP dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your MVC controller method to use `@ModelAttribute` (i hope your are using annotations)

```
@RequestMapping("/somepath/foo/do")
public String someHandlerMethod(
   @ModelAttribute("commandObject") CommandObject commandObject,
   Model model, 
   BindingResult result) {

     commandObject.setSomeValue("sample"); //Set value in command object

     ...processing...
     return("some.jsp");
}
```

Comment: Hey I don't have the scope to return it from the controller.It has to be handled in JSP itself.

Comment: You cannot handle it just with JSP because <form:> tags are managed by Spring , unless the data reaches Spring Controller , it cannot handle it , can it!